# How to make HasMany Relation ship in Laravel 4.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4.2

I have a user model looks like this

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

    public function answer(){
        return $this->hasMany('Answer','user_id');
    }

    public function supplierranking(){
        return $this->hasMany('Supplierrank','userid','id');
    }
}
```

Now each user will rank a company in a ranking Model which looks like this

```
Class Supplierrank extends Eloquent{
    public function supplier(){
        return $this->belongsTo('Supplier','supplierid','id');
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('User','userid','id');
    }

}
```

I am able to get the user with the ranking details but I also have to get the details of companies that has been ranked from a Supplier table

which looks like this

```
Class Supplier extends Eloquent{
    public function supplierranks(){
        return $this->hasMany('Supplierrank','supplierid');
    }

}
```

My query that I have done looks like this

```
$usersandranking = User::where('event','=',$exceleve)->with('supplierranking')->orderBy('id')->get();
```

It gets me user detail and there rankings but not the supplier names

Can any one help me on this